# How to display background image in text view

Tags: android

can anybody tell how to display background image in a `TextView` in android?

Comment: atleast try to do upvote or accept some answer as you can !!!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you are working with xmls you can add it as Praveen Chandrasekaran said doing:

```
android:background="@drawable/myResouce"
```

Before that you have to put your image file inside the res/drawable folder.

You can also change it from the code doing:

```
  mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myResouce);
```

Comment: What about, if I need to change background image programmatically from the string? For example I`ve got one "myResource";, as U can see I can't do that in R.drawable.etc style.

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` when API is >16

Comment: Will it center the text on top of the image?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky use android:gravity="center" and it will center the text on the image

Answer (score 4):

add a `android:background="@drawable/imagefile"` attribute on your `TextView` tag. Before that  you have to put your image file inside the `res/drawable` folder.

Answer (score 1):

android:background="@drawable/mark"

Also review.... your background image should be a 9.png and add some paddings for your content

```
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp" android:background="@drawable/mark"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingLeft=
```